# Как удалить строку таблицы в зависимости от значения в этой строке при помощи jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть вот такая таблица:

```html
<table border>
  <tr>
    <th>Имя</th>
    <th>Пол</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Николай</td>
    <td>Мужчина</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Елена</td>
    <td>Женщина</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Василий</td>
    <td>Мужчина</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы каждая строка содержащяя "женщину", удалялась\стиралась. При этом мне нужно это реализовать при помощи jQuery. Я провозился с этим уже несколько часов, но так ни к чему и не пришел...

Comment: "Я провозился с этим уже несколько часов, но так ни к чему и не пришел" - поэтому просто напишите за меня код.

Comment: Собственно, а для чего создан данный сайт?) Я не прошу написать за меня код, достаточно было бы хотя бы подсказать, как такое реализовать\или какие методы могут помочь.

Comment: Вам могут помочь методы `each`, `text`, `closest` и `remove`.